# How to get data from localstorage into text field without button

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some problems to trying get array data from local storage to textfield. can some one help me ?

```
<body>
    <button id="get">GET</button>
    <input type="text" id="name"/>

<script>
    let dataArray = ["sapi", "kambing", "kelinci"];
    let str2 = JSON.stringify(dataArray)
    window.localStorage.setItem("data_object", str2)
            
    let str = JSON.parse(dataArray)             
    let name = localStorage.getItem('data_object',str);
    document.querySelector('#name').value
</script>
```

Comment: The last three lines are bad: 1. you're trying to parse an Array as opposed to JSON text 2. there's no 2nd param in getItem 3. `document.querySelector('#name').value` on its own does nothing

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Right now, you successfully serialize an array to a string and store it in local storage. If you want to get the data out of local storage, simply reverse the steps. Get the data out of local storage, deserialize it, and set the value property of the `input` element to a string that represents your data.

Comment: okay i'll try. thanks for your answer sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one?

```html
<body>
<button  id="get">GET</button>
<input  type="text"  id="name"  />
</body>
<script>
let  dataArray = ["sapi", "kambing", "kelinci"];
window.localStorage.setItem("data_object", JSON.stringify(dataArray))

document.querySelector("#get").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let  storageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data_object"));
    document.querySelector('#name').value = storageArray;
});
</script>
´´´
```